# How to dynamically bind options to a select2 element

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a select2 dropdown which has to get its options dynamically as user types the letters.

**HTML:**

```
<select class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible ddlSegments" multiple=""></select>
```

Here is the function that triggers for each letter that user types.

**JS:**

```
function GetSegmentsByKeyword(ddlSegments, keyword) {
    $(ddlSegments).html("").trigger("change");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Common/GetSegmentsByKeyword",
        data: "{'keyword': " + JSON.stringify(keyword) + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",            
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.Segments.length > 0) {
                //bind data
                var options = "";
                var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(response.Segments);

                $.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
                    options += '<option value="' + obj.SegmentValue + '">' + obj.DisplayName + '</option>';
                });

                $(ddlSegments).append(options);                
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the problem I experience:
When user entered say '12', the relevant data from table is returned and bound to the options. But the popup list doesn't show up. It shows up only after user types another letter.

i.e, when user types '12', the correct data is bound and doesn't show the list. But when user types '123', the list shows up. However, the data in the list is only related to '12'. When user types '1234', the list shows up with data related to '123'.

What should be done, so that the select2 list shows up dynamically right after binding the data.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you missed to trigger event on key up in select2 like this for example 
`$(document).on('keyup', '.ddlSegments', function (e)`, 
please check the fiddle here: [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/surajwork/j70hbxce)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `minimumSearchLength` configuration parameter.  [Here](https://select2.org/searching#minimum-search-term-length) is the documentation.

```
$('select').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3 // only start searching when the user has input 3 or more characters
});
```